# How can I filter a dataframe by a subset of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply a filter to a dataframe based on whether a certain string is a substring of the values in a column.

For example: Let's call the substring 'X' and I want to retrieve all rows where 'X' is a substring of the value in a column called 'A'.

It feels like the code should look something like this:

```
df["X" in df.A]
```

or this:

```
df.loc("X" in df.A)
```

or something along those lines. Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
res = df[df['A'].str.contains("X")]
```